# How to change the primary color of the react built-in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am using react built-in bootstrap(The one without importing any library and installing extra package) for my website. Right now, I need a customised primary colour. How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To customize Bootstrap, create a file called src/custom.scss (or similar) and import the Bootstrap source stylesheet. Add any overrides before the imported file(s). You can reference Bootstrap's documentation for the names of the available variables.
Bootstrap's documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/#css-variables

Make sure you have sass installed:

```bash
npm i sass
#or for yarn
yarn add sass
```

For example:

```
// change the theme
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #0074d9,
  "danger": #ff4136
);

// Import Bootstrap and its default variables
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Finally, import the newly created .scss file instead of the default Bootstrap .css in the beginning of your src/index.js file, for example:

```
import './custom.scss';
```

Read more:
https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-bootstrap#using-a-custom-theme

**Update (Jan 2023):**
You can use the CSS `:root` selector to set custom CSS variables for the primary color of Bootstrap.

First, you will need to define a custom CSS variable for the primary color. You can do this by adding the following code to the top of your CSS file:

```
:root {
  --primary-color: #your-color-code;
}
```

Then, you can use this custom variable throughout your CSS to change the primary color of Bootstrap elements. For example, to change the color of all `.btn-primary` buttons:

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

You can use this same technique to change other colors as well, by changing the CSS variable in the `:root` selector and then using it in your CSS.

It is also possible to achieve this by creating a new css file with the customised css variables and import that file after importing bootstrap in your `index.js` file.

Comment: You have to put `$theme-colors` before Bootstrap css import.

Comment: Do I have to import `bootstrap.min.css` as well? If I don't my stilling falls apart.

Comment: `node-sass` is deprecated. To enable scss you should run `npm install sass`. Link: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/